# Tool to normalize tag order in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a collection of XML files that have been manually maintained and I need to clean them up and compare them. I've found lots of tools to clean up the indentation but I would also like to re-order the tags in a consistent order. I can obviously write a script to do this, but if I need this I'm sure others have encountered this problem as well.

Does anyone know of a tool that will re-order the tags so that I can more easily compare multiple XML files?

Answer (score 2):

If your XML data really has no significant order among elements, you can normalize the order easily enough:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
    <xsl:sort select="namespace-uri()"/>
    <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>
  ...
 ...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of XML elements, unlike that of XML attributes, is significant by default.  Therefore, tools will typically ***not*** reorder elements – it's not like cleaning-up indentation.

See tools that support [XML Normalization Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/2008/xmlsec/Drafts/xml-norm/) or the [Canonical XML Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n) if your application has a need for standardizing attribute ordering.

And, of course, XSLT can be used for general transformations, including re-ordering of elements, according to user-defined criteria.